# #include <iostream>

Tags: json, visual-studio, iostream

While trying to install sdl2 on my Mac, Visual Studio went wrong and the program cannot locate iostream. I am kindly asking for help how to make it visible for VisualStudio

[image]

And this is c_cpp_properties.json files

[image]